Is there a way to run macro's in an Excel Workbook that is on Sharepoint without kicking the other users out?
I understand that macros do not work in excel web, which is why we only open the workbook in the excel app, which still migrates with sharepoint. So all of the macros within the workbook still run just fine.
However, the issue is that whenever I run a macro while another user is in the spreadsheet, they are immediately kicked out or locked out and are forced to re-open the workbook.
At first I thought that there was an issue with the macro I was running which may have kicked the user out, but I've come to find that regardless of how simple the macro is doesn't matter; and that anytime I run ANY macro, the other users in the workbook will still be kicked out or locked out and have to re-open it.
Is there a solution to this problem? Or does my workbook simply need to be taken out of shared mode so that only one user can make changes at a time?
Like I said, I've tried digging into each individual macro to see if they contain something that might be causing the other users to be kicked out. But haven't found anything.
It doesn't seem to matter what the macro is doing, because even the simplest macro when ran will kick the other users out.

This question is similar to: Is there a way to use macros in Excel online version(office 365)?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
